# Support for gradient directly in theme configurations in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Right now we can configure the theme in material-ui as follows.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff4400'
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // error: will use the default color
  },
});
```

Is there a way to provide **gradient configuration** for primary and secondary colours? IMHO subtle gradients give better colour pops and make the flat colours slightly less boring

Answer (score 11):

You could set gradient values inside of your theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ff4400',
      mainGradient: "linear-gradient(to right, tomato, cyan)",
    },
    // ...
  },
});
```

And then use this value inside of components `style` prop:

```
<AppBar
  position="static"
  style={{ background: theme.palette.primary.mainGradient }}
> ...
```

**EDIT**

This is indeed feels hacky, but i believe this is the only way at the moment. I haven't found any examples of this in the MUI docs. And if you check out the [source of `<AppBar />`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/AppBar/AppBar.js) component, you'll find out that it is impossible to use `main`, `light` or `dark` colors as linear-gradients:

```
export const styles = theme => {
  //...

  return {
    /* ... */

    /* Styles applied to the root element if `color="primary"`. */
    colorPrimary: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main, 
      color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    },
    /* Styles applied to the root element if `color="secondary"`. */
    colorSecondary: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
    },
  };
};
```

As you can see `backgroundColor` is used here. It would be invalid to set `linear-gradient(...)` to it.

Comment: This is a little hackish given that I will have to do it every time. Was just wondering if something is provided out of the box, just like the primary and secondary colors

Comment: Wondering if this is still the go-to way to go in 2021, indeed this does feel hacky but I've also been recommended styling this way.